# semantic server Virtuoso connection failed

Tags: semantic-web, dbpedia, virtuoso

I set up Virtuoso 7 with DBpedia 3.9 [according to this tutorial](https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/04/23/setting-up-a-local-dbpedia-3-9-mirror-with-virtuoso-7/), and when I do this, connection fails. Anyone know what goes wrong?

```
root@sunxd-Latitude-E5550:/media/sunxd/Repo/LinkedDataRepo/datasets/dbpedia/3.9# isql
OpenLink Interactive SQL (Virtuoso), version 0.9849b.
Type HELP; for help and EXIT; to exit.
SQL> ld_dir_all('/media/sunxd/Repo/LinkedDataRepo/datasets/dbpedia/3.9/dbpedia.org','*.*','http://dbpedia.org');

*** Error S2801: [Virtuoso Driver]CL033: Connect failed to localhost:1111 = localhost:1111.
at line 1 of Top-Level:
```

Comment: Potentially of interest to folks trying to do this -- OpenLink (my employer) has made available an [EBS-backed, Pay-as-you-go AMI, based on Virtuoso 7, and populated with DBpedia 2015 a/k/a DBpedia 3.10](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtPayAsYouGoEBSBackedAMIDBpedia2015).

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to fix the problem

1. since I didn't make any symbolic link as the tutorial said, so

   ```
   ld_dir_all('/media/sunxd/Repo/LinkedDataRepo/datasets/dbpedia/3.9/dbpedia.org','*.*','http://dbpedia.org');
   ```

   should be changed to

   ```
    ld_dir_all('/media/sunxd/Repo/LinkedDataRepo/datasets/dbpedia/3.9','*.*','http://dbpedia.org');
   ```
2. be sure to edit the init file and restart afterwards

Comment: Note that DBpedia 3.9 is more than a year out of date. Current dumps are 3.10, as mentioned in my comment on question...